# read specific line range from file

Tags: python, readline

imho a pretty simple problem, but i cant find a solution.

i first get all files from a directory and read them in. after that i have a regex if statement.
if we have a match, i need the line number cause thats where a new config part starts. after getting all line numbers i want to read the lines from match1 to match2. next from match3 to match4 and from match 4 to the end of the file.

file:

> PROMOPT# show startup-config 
> !
> hostname bla 
> !
> no banner motd
>
> PROMPT# show system
>
> sysinfo(System Information)
> Main Memory Size    : 512 MB
> flash Memory Size   : 256 MB
> H/W Revision        : VA0
> NOS Version         : 1.15
>
> PROMPT# show version
>
> NOS version 1.15_0006

Code:

```
for file in files:
        with open (file, 'r') as file:
            for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
                line = line.strip()
                if re.findall(r'(PROMTP#)', line):
                    configpart = line.split()
                    configpart = configpart[2]

                    print('name: ', configpart, 'linenumber: ', num)
```

Output:

name:  startup-config linenumber:  1 
name:  system linenumber:  58
name:  version linenumber:  70 
name: startup-config linenumber:  1 
name:  system linenumber:  58 
name: version linenumber:  70

so now i want to

file.readlines()[1:57] 
file.readlines()[58:69]
file.readlines()[70:to end of file]

but i cant figure out a loop doing this for me.

Comment: You can't `readlines()` again unless you rewind the file to the beginning. A better approach entirely would be to read the lines into an array first, and then loop over that. But your parser looks rather brittle even then; if you see the same marker twice, you just overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read all of the lines into a variable, then perform your operations on this variable.

I am not sure about your desired output exactly, but I would probably store them in a dictionary and then extract them using file name.

```py
import re
files = ["files/sample.txt"]
output = {}
for file in files:
    with open (file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        output[file] = []
        command = []
        for line in lines:
            if "PROMPT" in line and lines.index(line) != 0:
                output[file].append(command)
                command = []
            command.append(line)
        output[file].append(command)

# then to extract
# first command
output[your_file_name][0] 
# second command
output[your_file_name][1] 
# another file
output[your_file_name_1][0] 

# or..
for command in output[your_file_name:
    do_something_with_command(command)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, you helped me alot. I wanted a nested dict and with your help i was finally able to get what i wanted. it looks smth like this:

'filename': { "['startup-config']": 'val1', 'val2'], "['system']": 'val1', 'val2', 'val3']}